# Compare value obtained from textbox in asp(vb) using SQL Server database

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am using asp(vb)

In SQL Server database I made a table `cars` which has two columns:

- `productid int`
- `name varchar(50)`

Now I am collecting the value of name attribute from user through a text field:

Enter car name

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
```

and storing it in a variable:

```
name = Request.Form("name")
```

But when I run this query, it gives error:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM cars where name = " & name
```

Unable to figure out why?

Comment: Try to run the query `select * from cars where name=whatever` with the MSSQL query analyzer. You'll get a syntax error. Fix it and do the same in your code.

Comment: **WHAT** error does it give you??

Comment: @marc_s : An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.

Comment: That doesn't sound like anything from the database - must be some other error / flaw in your application...

Comment: Hello, sql injection vulnerability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `name` is defined as a `VARCHAR` string datatype, this would mean you need to quote the value of `name` in your SQL query, ie

```
query = "SELECT *  FROM cars WHERE name = '" & name & "'"
```

or better still, use a [parameterised query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190) via a `ADODB.Command` object if you're using ADODB

Answer (score 0):

I think u first run a query for `INSERT` the data

Comment: Are u trying to find out that car name which is enter by user is present in your table or not?

Answer (score 0):

Using MSSql Server? Try:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM cars where [name] = " & name
```

Note the [] around the name column.